# Validate if the insert was completed successfully

Tags: sql, insert

I want to know how can i validate if my Insert was successful, for example i have this query:

```
 INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('TEST01');
```

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 EXPRESS and am running that from Java, but I am calling a Store procedure so I can't get a boolean answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@@ROWCOUNT` after your insert statement. it Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

if it returns grater than `0` it means your rows has been inserted successfully

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this.

1. Use a try catch block. Insert statement in the try block. Then handle the exception in catch block.
2. Use the global variable `@@error` to check if it is non-zero then the previous statement has resulted in error.

There might be other ways as well but these are the ones I can think of now.

These options will catch the error after the insert statement has run. You can also write some sql code to ensure that insert statement is executed only if the values pass data validation checks.